# Getting the Size from Size.Width property

Tags: c#

I have a form where a user inputs text and that text is to be printed on a label of varying sizes (depending on what label the user picks). Each label has been measured and its width is declared in points. I then calculate the size of the inputted text via:

```
int labelWidth; 
Font defaultFont = new Font("Arial", fontSizeDefault, FontStyle.Regular); 
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(inputtedText, defaultFOnt);
int width = textSize.Width;
Size newSize = scaleText(textSize, width, labelWidth);
```

With this I have how wide the text is and how long the label is depending on what's selected. I then pass the `size`, `width`, and `labelWidth` into a method that should return a new size to use that ensures the text will fit the label:

```
// I know I'll want to return a Size Struct to use to print the label
private Size scaleText(Size size, int width, int labelWidth) {
    if (width< labelWidth) {
        return size; // an easy return if it doesn't need scaling
    } else {
        while (width >= labelWidth) {
            width--;
        }
        // pseudo code to get the new size based on a width < labelWidth
    }
}

// returned Size would then be used in a ZPL-string to print the label
```

Hopefully that explains my thinking with this, and so where I'm stuck is turning that width that was ever decreasing to fit the labelWidth back into a Size structure to be returned and used with the `^A` command in ZPL. Is this possible or should I start from scratch with another way? Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: Don't you mean `while (width >= labelWidth)`? Also, you aren't computing a new width based on reducing the font size in your loop, so the loop is just doing a subtraction the hardware (e.g. `width = labelWidth-1`). Reduce the font size, then computer a new `textSize` and you can return it once `Width` is small enough.

Comment: @NetMage Yes you're correct on the while loop, I hastily typed it out but my code does have it as you said. I'll give your way a go because that makes a lot of sense and I was tunnel-visioned on the way I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are trying to print on a label and reduce the output text size to fit, you really are trying to scale your font until the width of the text is less than the label width.

So you should be computing the font (size) to use on the label like so:

```
Font labelFont = scaleFont(inputtedText, "Arial", FontStyle.Regular, fontSizeDefault, labelWidth);

public Font scaleFont(string text, string fontName, FontStyle fontStyle, int startingFontSize, int labelWidth) {
    for (int fontSize = startingFontSize; fontSize > 1; --fontSize) {
        Font trialFont = new Font(fontName, fontSize, fontStyle);
        Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, trialFont);
        if (textSize.Width < labelWidth)
            return trialFont;
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

My `scaleFont` method returns `null` for when it is unable to fit the text on the label. Your program will need to handle this error or have a minimum font size and cut off the too long text.

Comment: Much appreciated. I'll set handling of those extreme cases while trying your method. Thank you!